# onClick attribute is showing some error while configuration with button

Tags: android, onclick

How to resolve this problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvEVK.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

there is another android:onClick : [image: android:onClick]

or instead of Button

use :

androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton